# Can I set default VLC args when double clicking a video file?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm trying to get VLC to start with certain args, and I've already edited the Start Menu entry, to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --intf rc --rc-host localhost:1234 --rc-quiet`, which works fine, but when I double click a video file, it opens in a new VLC window, I guess because it's starting VLC with no args. Is there anyway I can make this work?

The arguments I've set, from what I can see, cannot be set all in the preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Note you will need this registry key for *each file type you wish to open with VLC*. I will use `MP4` for this example.

Add the following registry key (It may not currently exist):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\VLC.mp4\shell\Open\command
```

For the default value of this key:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --intf rc --rc-host localhost:1234 --rc-quiet --started-from-file "%1"
```

[image]

Now when you double click any MP4 file associated with VLC, it will open with your additional arguments. Note that for VLC you must have `--started-from-file "%1"` or it will not open the file.

Alternatively, if you're not comfortable editing the registry or don't want to, you can use [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/). Navigate to `File Type Settings`, `Context Menu`, find the extension you wish to change the arguments for and change the `Play` command to include the arguments you need.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, my OS is Windows 10. I tried the regedit, which didn't work, however, the Default Programs Editor worked a treat, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should write a .bat or .cmd or .ps1 script which starts vlc with your favourite options and the command line arguments that are given to the script.
Then you can assign that script as default application to any/all the media extensions you can think of.